# How to increase the buffer size of .tex file to store huge data in windows?

Tags: pdf, latex, tex

I am using latex template for creating pdf with huge data, I got an error "fileName.tex! Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000.Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf".
Since pdf has huge data,can I resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This {Tex} answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43438) applies to the current question. Essentially you should set the variable

```
buf_size=200000
```

in the file texmf.cnf to a higher value of your choosing. This file resides in your texlive (or miktex or which ever distribution of latex you use) directories. You can try to locate it by using the command

```
kpsewhich texmf.cnf
```

in the command line, but I'm not sure if every Windows command line will be able to find the kpsewhich tool by default (otherwise the command will result in an error message).

As has been pointed out in a comment to the answer linked above, you can also change the buffer size in the environment of the command. This, however would mean that you would have to run pdflatex from the command line, stating

```
buf_size=100000 pdflatex (your-latex-source-file).tex
```

Depending on what kind of "huge data" the pdf contains, there may be another way to solve the problem. If it is just large amounts of large floats (images, tables, code listings) the placement of which pdflatex defers for too long (thereby filling up the buffer), you can force immediate placement by including the

```
\clearpage
```

command now and then in your LaTeX code. This will force pdflatex to flush all floats from the buffer and place them immediately wherever the clearpage command is issued.

Edit: In miktex (which I do not have), the configuration seems to be different. Configuration files seem to be changed like so: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/runtimeparams.html
An overview over all changable runtime parameters (which includes buf_size) is given here: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/defaults.html

Comment: thanx @orange for this solution.I have another query that am using xelatex command in nodejs to generate pdf, the pdf name will be dynamic,and in miketex the texmf.cnf file is not available so that for it I installed texlive and got texmf.cnf and set the buffer size, but it didn't work. can you riview  it and give some suggestion. thanx.

Comment: @ABarik you are right, miktex seems to be slightly different; the miktex documentation has instructions for how to deal with this; see the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Hi @0range I have read the docs of miktex, but still the issue is same didn't find the texmf file in it.
And when I give "initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex", it opens simple paflatex or xelatex .txt file with no content.
Can you give the solution to increase buffer_size with command line or manual setting. 
Thanx for your interest.